# Unable to sign-up using email/password (Firebase NodeJS SDK)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a sign-up form which allows Users to enter their credentials (email, password, etc.), which should create a Firebase Auth account, and a record of the other details in MongoDB.
My required flow is that the User enters their details, clicks on the sign-up button, which executes the following sequence:

1. first makes a `POST` request to save the details in MongoDB
2. `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method provided by `getAuth()`. I'm also modifying the claims of the created account by using the `beforeUserCreated` and `beforeUserSignedIn` methods imported from `firebase-functions/v2/identity` in Firebase Functions, just before the account is actually created.

I'm consistently getting an error recently, and the error logs aren't very helpful to me. Even `signInWithGoogle` gives this same error in the browser:

Error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/error-code:-47).
    at Tn (assert.ts:136:55)
    at vn (assert.ts:65:9)
    at Mn (index.ts:210:9)
    at async Rn (index.ts:231:9)
    at async ai (email_and_password.ts:283:9)
```

Here's the code for the user authentication:

EmailSignUp function that handles the form submission for email/password account:

```
function emailSignUp(event) {
        setSignUpClicked(true);
        event.preventDefault();
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            console.log("Passwords do not match!");
            setSignUpClicked(false);
            return;
        }

        // let files = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files;
        let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("emailSignUp"));

        fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOYED_API_URL}/auth/user/register`, {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                if (data.status === "error") {
                    setStatus("failure");
                    setSignUpClicked(false);
                    throw new Error("Invalid form input. Please check again.");
                } else {
                    // fix auth-function deadline error by maybe creating firebase user first.
                    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
                        .then((userCredential) => {
                            // Signed Up
                            setStatus("success");
                            setSignUpClicked(false);
                            setShowMyModal(true);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            const errorCode = error.code;
                            const errorMessage = error.message;
                            setStatus("failure");
                            setSignUpClicked(false);
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                    console.log("Success:", data);
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                setStatus("failure");
                setSignUpClicked(false);
                console.error("Error:", error);
            });

        /* 
            
             */
    }
```

index.js (Firebase Functions)

```
export const beforecreated = beforeUserCreated(async (event) => {
    try {
        const email = event.data.email;
        const checkUser = await User.findOne({ email: event.data.email });

        //when sign in with google is clicked
        if (event.additionalUserInfo.providerId === "google.com") {
            const checkOrg = await Organization.findOne({ email });
            if (checkUser) {
                return {
                    displayName: checkUser.name,
                    customClaims: {
                        role: "user",
                        userId: checkUser._id,
                    },
                };
            } else if (checkOrg) {
                return {
                    displayName: checkUser.name,
                    customClaims: {
                        role: "org",
                        orgId: checkUser._id,
                    },
                };
            } else {
                //google sign in and user not in db
                //create user in db
                const name = event.data.displayName;
                const email = event.data.email;
                const photoURL = event.data.photoURL;

                const response = await fetch(photoURL);
                const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
                console.log("BUFFER: ", buffer);
                const storagePath = `user/${email}/profile.jpeg`;
                const storageRef = ref(storage, storagePath);
                const metadata = {
                    contentType: "image/jpeg",
                };
                const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(
                    storageRef,
                    buffer,
                    metadata
                );
                if (snapshot.state === "success") {
                    const user = await User.create({
                        name,
                        email,
                        photoPathFirestore: storagePath,
                    });
                    console.log("Successfully created new user in DB!");
                    return {
                        displayName: user.name,
                        customClaims: {
                            role: "user",
                            userId: user._id,
                        },
                    };
                } else {
                    throw new Error("Error occurred while creating User");
                }
            }
        } else {
            //email/password sign in
            if (checkUser) {
                return {
                    customClaims: {
                        role: "user",
                    },
                };
            }
            return {
                customClaims: {
                    role: "org",
                },
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
});

export const beforesignin = beforeUserSignedIn(async (event) => {
    try {
        const email = event.data.email;
        const checkUser = await User.findOne({ email });

        if (checkUser) {
            return {
                displayName: checkUser.name,
                customClaims: {
                    role: "user",
                    userId: checkUser._id,
                },
            };
        } else {
            const checkOrg = await Organization.findOne({ email });
            return {
                displayName: checkOrg.name,
                customClaims: {
                    role: "org",
                    orgId: checkOrg._id,
                },
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        throw new Error(err);
    }
});
```

`api/user/register` to create the User in DB

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { name, email, phone } = req.body;

        //email variable, update record in DB
        if (!name || !email) {
            throw new Error(
                "Following fields are mandatory: name, email, password, photo"
            );
        } else {
            if (!req.files[0]) {
                throw new Error(
                    "Following fields are mandatory: name, email, password, photo"
                );
            }
            const file = req.files[0];
            const filename = file.originalname;
            const extension = filename.split(".").pop();
            if (
                extension !== "png" &&
                extension !== "jpg" &&
                extension !== "jpeg"
            ) {
                response_400(
                    res,
                    "Invalid file format. Only .jpg, .png, .jpeg files are allowed"
                );
            } else {
                // Resize image and get extension
                Jimp.read(file.buffer)
                    .then((image) => {
                        // Convert the image to JPEG with quality 100 (you can adjust the quality as needed)
                        return image
                            .quality(100)
                            .getBufferAsync(Jimp.MIME_JPEG);
                    })
                    .then(async (jpegBuffer) => {
                        console.log("Image converted successfully!");
                        // Now you have the converted buffer (jpegBuffer) that you can use

                        const pathToFile = `user/${email}/profile.jpeg`;
                        const storageRef = ref(storage, pathToFile);

                        const metadata = {
                            contentType: "image/jpeg",
                        };

                        const snapshot = await uploadBytesResumable(
                            storageRef,
                            jpegBuffer,
                            metadata
                        );
                        if (snapshot.state === "success") {
                            const user = await User.create({
                                name,
                                email,
                                photoPathFirestore: pathToFile,
                                phone,
                            });
                            console.log("Successfully created new user in DB!");
                            response_200(
                                res,
                                "Successfully created new user in DB"
                            );
                        } else {
                            response_500(
                                res,
                                "Error occurred while uploading user file"
                            );
                        }
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        console.error("Error converting image:", err);
                        response_500(res, "Error converting image");
                    });
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.send(err);
    }
});
```

How do I get rid of the `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/error-code:-47).` error?

Comment: can you confirm that the signIn With Google and signIn With Email Password is allowed in your firebase console?

Comment: @Rainysidewalks yes, I have them enabled. This `auth/error-code:-47` has started occurring very recently. Before, I was able to use both of these Providers (but even then, I used to get another error sometimes: `auth-error/cloud-function:deadline_exceeded`. Refreshing the page would weirdly make this go away for that session.)

Answer (score 0):

please try the following

```
async function emailSignUp(event) {
    setSignUpClicked(true);
    event.preventDefault();
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
        console.log("Passwords do not match!");
        setSignUpClicked(false);
        return;
    }

    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // here signed Up then rest of the code flow
            setStatus("success");
            setSignUpClicked(false);
            setShowMyModal(true);

            let formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("emailSignUp"));
          

            fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_DEPLOYED_API_URL}/auth/user/register`, {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData,
            })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                    if (data.status === "error") {
                        setStatus("failure");
                        throw new Error("Invalid form input. Please check again.");
                    } else {
                        console.log("Success:", data);
                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    setStatus("failure");
                    console.error("Error:", error);
                });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            setStatus("failure");
            setSignUpClicked(false);
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

here i moved all the code including the `fetch` inside the then of `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` , there may be other reason for the error but please try and let me know .

Comment: I tried this; doesn't work. Still getting the same error:
```FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/error-code:-47).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:136:1)
    at _fail (assert.ts:65:1)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:210:1)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:231:1)
    at async createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email_and_password.ts:283:1)```

which means that the Firebase Auth method is resulting in the issue.

Comment: also above this error in the browser console, I just realised there's another error coming:
```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 () (https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=<key>)```

Comment: try with `async` and `await`,  can you just check is your connection is ok, also do you have any idea how may request are being made to the serve backend per second

Comment: didn't work by changing to async/await either. connection is alright, and since I'm testing on a dev environment, the requests are very less as of now.

Comment: can you share your imports and how you are initiating the `auth` ,and what version you are using?

Comment: `const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.BUCKET_ID,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
initializeApp(config);
const auth = getAuth(); export {auth}`
this is my firebase.config.js

Comment: also, I think the error might be because of Cloud Blocking Functions (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/blocking-functions)

I tried disabling them, and it seems to work flawlessly. But I require to manage multiple different users, for which I had enabled Cloud Blocking Functions to modify the logged in User object before creation/signin (beforeUserCreated, beforeUserSignedIn methods provided by firebase-functions/v2/identity)